# Creating a ruby-on-rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ibm-midrange, rails-activerecord

I have an existing model that connects to an AS400 DB and I need to create a new model like it that connects to a new file and pulls one field (an email address) and then loops through it 5 times. This shouldn't be difficult however I have never done this in Ruby and I can't seem to get it to work. Any help that would point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the existing model:

```
 class Distributor < ActiveRecord::Base

 establish_connection "as400_#{RAILS_ENV}"
set_table_name "DISTJ01"

# TODO: what to return if no distributor?
# Create array of hashed distributor info.
def self.get_distributors_by_state state, preferred_distributor
    d = []
    # see validate_distributor_number below
    # If they have a preferred distributor, pull that one and make it first so it will default to that.
    if !preferred_distributor.blank?
        s = Distributor.find_by_sql ["SELECT CNAM05 cnam05, CUSNP1 cusnp1 FROM DISTJ01 WHERE CUSNP1 = ?", preferred_distributor]
        d << { :name => s[0].cnam05, :id => s[0].cusnp1 }   unless s.blank?
    end

    # If they have an account number, they can choose to purchase direct in addition to choosing a distributor.
    # Per Ron 4/20/11, removed this.
    #d << { :name => "DIRECT PURCHASE", :id => account_number } unless account_number.blank?

    # Get all other available distributors for this state.
    s = Distributor.find_by_sql ["SELECT CNAM05 cnam05, CUSNP1 cusnp1 FROM DISTJ01 WHERE STATEP2 = ? AND CUSNP1 <> ? ORDER BY CNAM05", state.upcase, preferred_distributor]
    unless s.blank?
        s.each do |t|
            d << { :name => t.cnam05, :id => t.cusnp1 }
        end
    end
    d
end

def self.validate_distributor_number distributor_number, user
    # We need to make sure that the distributor number we are assigning
    # is valid. Since it comes from a form post, somebody could pick
    # another number if they wanted. We can't have that. Granted they
    # already had to logon so they are a legit user, but, they still
    # could try to trick us.
    if distributor_number.strip == user.as400_fields[:account_number].strip
        distributor_number
    else

        # If a DSD account chooses to purchase from their preferred distributor, we use the customer number from
        # the sign-on table, not from the distributor.
        if user.as400_fields[:preferred_distributor] == distributor_number and user.as400_fields[:account_type].strip == "DSD"
            user.as400_fields[:account_number]
        else
            d = Distributor.find_by_sql ["SELECT CUSNP1 cusnp1 FROM DISTJ01, SIGNONS " +
                "WHERE DISTJ01.STATEP2 = SIGNONS.BSSTCDW1 AND SIGNONS.USERW1 = ? AND DISTJ01.CUSNP1 = ?", user.login.upcase, distributor_number]
            d[0].cusnp1 unless d.blank?
        end
    end
end

 end
```

The new connection needs to be the table WEBOEL23 and the filed is EMAL23. Here is what I have so far what do I need to add:

```
 class Weboel23 < ActiveRecord::Base

establish_connection "as400_#{RAILS_ENV}"
set_table_name "WEBOEL23"

 def self.get_email_by_account email, cono23
    d = []
    if !emal23.blank?
        s = email.find_by_sql ["SELECT ACT223 act223,EMAL23 emal23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 = ?", CONO23]         
        d << { :name => s[0].act223, :id => s[0].emal23 }   unless s.blank?
      end    
   end
 end
```

The model seems better now but it is now failing on the order.rb page when I call the field from the model what am I missing?

```
  weboel23 = Weboel23.first(:conditions => {:cusnp1 => distributor_number}, :select => "EMAL23")
```

Comment: In your model, email is a local variable. In your Order.rb (controller?), you're referring to a model named Email. But the model you created is Weboel23.

Comment: updated the above question with a modified call to the model

Comment: After that, you've got me. I'm not much expert on fancy selectors. Did you try the query in the rails Console (see below)?

Answer (score 1):

Bob. You are about 10 miles from here!

By "connects to a new file" do you mean a new table? set_table_name "DISTJ01" would seem to set the table (normally the table would automatically be the same as the model name).

The two existing methods in the model would seem to be irrelevent.

Seems your new method should just access emal23 and perform the logic. (But I'm not at all a model guru.)

Or do you mean that it connects to the Distj01 table and writes the new file/table weboel23?

### ed

OK, I'm not an existing db guy, but I think you can create your model at the command line with

```
rails generate model
```

or, if you don't mind adding more files, you can generate an entire mvc with

```
rails generate scaffold
```

In either case, you would give it the table name, followed by the fields and data types

```
rails generate model Weboel23 emal23:string
```

If this works, you can then run a rails console

```
rails console
```

and peer into the app to see what's there.

```
irb(main):001:0> Weboel23.all
```

or

```
> Weboel23.find(1)
```

to find the record with id 1

Info on the rails command line is here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate

Comment: yes the 400 guys call everything files but you are correct, the set_table_name "DISTJ01" would in this case need to be changed to set_table_name "WEBOEL23 ".

Comment: I merely need access to the EMAL23 field and the loop can be done in another area.

Comment: (SO is slow on forwarding comments!) If you look in the db/schema.rb file, is there a definition of the weboel23 table?

Comment: ok I updated with where I am now, it appears to be connecting to the table but not sire I am getting EMAL23 field

Comment: no there is no db/schema.rb  only thing in that directory is seeds.rb

Comment: I added more to the answer.

Comment: Ok, I updated the above question. I think I am havging an issue in the logice of this call of the field form the model? (last part of the question)  thanks!